# Different implementation of query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query. I use phpmyadmin for testing and it executes perfectly. However when I try to use it in my server application I always get null on rank

```
SET @_c = 0;
SELECT kills,deaths,revives,damage,levels,rank,skill
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        (@_c \:= @_c + 1) AS `rank`, 
        ((kills + damage + levels)/(deaths+revives+1)) AS skill 
    FROM leaderboard 
    ORDER BY skill DESC) AS newtable 
WHERE soldier_id = 1(example)
```

I am looking either for another implementation or idea how to fix it.

Edit: I put (example) because soldier_id can be 1,2, or 3000. It not constant that what i am trying to say. And i have to use : because i use hibernate in java which requires it.

Comment: If you are running the same query against the same data, you **must** get the same result.

Comment: What are `\:=` and `1(example)`?  They look like syntax errors.

Comment: Based on a recent edit attempt it appears as if you have created duplicate accounts. If this is true please [merge your accounts](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Once your accounts are merged you'll be able to comment everywhere on this question and can edit your question without going through the review process.

Answer (score 0):

try..

```
SET @_c = 0;
SELECT kills,deaths,revives,damage,levels,rank,skill  
FROM (  SELECT  *,  (@_c \:= @_c + 1) AS `rank`,   
        ((kills + damage + levels)/(deaths+revives+1)) AS skill   
    FROM leaderboard   ) AS newtable   
WHERE soldier_id = 1(example)
ORDER BY skill DESC;
```

check for NOT NULL values in cols: kills, damage, levels, deaths, revives